# Promisse in constructor don't finish before method runs in angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-promise, oidc-client-js, oidc-client

promise from oidc-client in angular 10 constructor is taking too long to resolve, the isLoggedIn function is being called before the constructor places de value in the user variable.

this is my code:

```
import { UserManager, UserManagerSettings, User } from 'oidc-client';

export class AuthService {
  private user: User = null;
  private manager = new UserManager(getClientSettings());
  privatecachedRequests: Array<HttpRequest<any>> = [];

  constructor() {
    this.manager.getUser().then(user => {
      this.user = user;
    });
  }
  isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return this.user != null && !this.user.expired; <= this.user is null because the constructor did not finished the async part
  }
```

this code was working in angular 8

when I called getUser() function inside my isLoggedIn method, it worked, but i would like to use this from the constructor

Comment: where and how are you consuming `isLogged()` method?

Comment: AFAIK the issue is not related to Angular Version, Async execution needs to be handled appropriately, if you could provide some insight I would be able to give you the solution.

Comment: i'm using the isLogged() inside my route guard (canActivate)

  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
      return true;
    }
    this.authService.startAuthentication();
    return false;
  }

Comment: Ahan that would be enough ,Give me a moment.

Comment: Consider using an `APP_INITIALIZER` to configure perform the asynchronous initialization of the service.

Comment: thank you @AluanHaddad, i will search for your sugestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Rxjs` Subject to act as a proxy.

```
import {Subject } from 'rxjs',<-- add this
export class AuthService {
  private user: User = null;
  private manager = new UserManager(getClientSettings());
  privatecachedRequests: Array<HttpRequest<any>> = [];
  private loginSubject= new Subject()<-- add this line

  constructor() {
    this.manager.getUser().then(user => {
      this.user = user;
      if(this.user != null && !this.user.expired)
       {
         this.loginSubject.next(true)
       } else{
           this.loginSubject.next(false)
          }
     
    });
  }
  isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
     return this.loginSubject.asObservbale();<-- avoid leak 
  }
```

you can return Observable in canActivate

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService:AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean>  {
    return this.authService.isLoggedIn().pipe(
      map(res => {
        if (res) {
          return true;
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
           return false
        }
      })
  }   

}
```